# How to store each score whenever a gameobject collides with another gameobject inside an array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

A game in which a box will be punched, and the score of each destroyed box will be stored inside an array. I can retrieve the score of each punch, but I couldn't get to store them inside an array, for future use.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Punch") // If the box collides with the punch
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);                      //the box will be disappeared
            score[i] = addedValue;                    //put each score in array when the gameobject box is hit

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `List`

Comment: You can use Dictionary with key name and value gameobject, if gameobject have different name, It cool :D

Answer (score 0):

As Ted already commented, try a List<> object. It is dynamic in the way that you won't need to set it's size. It will adjust accordingly as you use the add() method.

To retrieve a "score" object, one might use getElementAt() method on the List.

```
List<Score> scores = new List<Score>();
scores.Add(new Score());
Score aScore = scores.getElementAt(0); // this gets Score located at index 0
```

If you don't want to use a List you can use a standard array.

```
Score[] scores = new Score[100]; // set number of scores in array
scores[0] = new Score();
Score aScore = scores[0];
```

This doesn't seem like too tricky a problem; would you mind clarifying with some code or an error you might be receiving?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this. I have put the code I have used which returns nothing when debugged. It is that it should store the each score in an array when each box is destroyed. I have put the snippet up there for your reference

Comment: Where is the initalisation of the score[]? If you haven't initialised it anywhere, then the compiler will definitely throw an error somewhere. And from the looks of the code, it appears that you are adding the same value to 10 spaces in the array.

Comment: I initialize it as int[] score = new int [10] as I have only 10 boxes. I see, do I need to make an array for addedValue too?

Comment: Is addedValue constant? It doesn't change between boxes?

Comment: It changes based on the time of the player to reach the box in time. If the player reach the box and punch it within time, the score will be one, else zero

Comment: Then you will not need to have an array for addedValue